# Three.js. Не добавляются объекты на сцену

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

На странице есть канвас, который рендерится через Three.js. Вот он:

Service.js

```
var Scamera = void 0,
    Sscene = void 0,
    Srenderer = void 0;
var Splane = void 0;
var Sraycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
var SnormalizedMouse = {
    x: 0,
    y: -180
};

var lightBlue = {
    r: 34,
    g: 183,
    b: 236
};

var darkBlue = {
    r: 0,
    g: 132,
    b: 184
};

var baseColorRGB = darkBlue;
var baseColor = "rgb(" + baseColorRGB.r + "," + baseColorRGB.g + "," + baseColorRGB.b + ")";
var nearStars = void 0,
    farStars = void 0,
    farthestStars = void 0;

var canv =  $('#service-bg canvas');

function init() {
    Scamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    Srenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

    // Scene initialization
    Scamera.position.z = 50;

    Srenderer.setClearColor("#121212", 1.0);
  var height = $('.services').innerHeight();
    Srenderer.setSize($(window).width(), height);
    Srenderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

    document.getElementById('service-bg').appendChild(Srenderer.domElement);

    // Lights
    var topLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
    topLight.position.set(0, 1, 1).normalize();
    Sscene.add(topLight);

    var bottomLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.4);
    bottomLight.position.set(1, -1, 1).normalize();
    Sscene.add(bottomLight);

    var skyLightRight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x666666, 0.2);
    skyLightRight.position.set(-1, -1, 0.2).normalize();
    Sscene.add(skyLightRight);

    var skyLightCenter = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x666666, 0.2);
    skyLightCenter.position.set(-0, -1, 0.2).normalize();
    Sscene.add(skyLightCenter);

    var skyLightLeft = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x666666, 0.2);
    skyLightLeft.position.set(1, -1, 0.2).normalize();
    Sscene.add(skyLightLeft);

    // Mesh creation
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(400, 400, 70, 70);
    var darkBlueMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, shading: THREE.FlatShading, side: THREE.DoubleSide, vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors });

    geometry.vertices.forEach(function (vertice) {
        vertice.x += (Math.random() - 0.5) * 4;
        vertice.y += (Math.random() - 0.5) * 4;
        vertice.z += (Math.random() - 0.5) * 4;
        vertice.dx = Math.random() - 0.5;
        vertice.dy = Math.random() - 0.5;
        vertice.randomDelay = Math.random() * 5;
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i++) {
        geometry.faces[i].color.setStyle(baseColor);
        geometry.faces[i].baseColor = baseColorRGB;
    }


    Splane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, darkBlueMaterial);
    Sscene.add(Splane);

    // Create stars
    farthestStars = createStars(1200, 420, "#0952BD");
    farStars = createStars(1200, 370, "#A5BFF0");
    nearStars = createStars(1200, 290, "#118CD6");

    Sscene.add(farthestStars);
    Sscene.add(farStars);
    Sscene.add(nearStars);

    farStars.rotation.x = 0.25;
    nearStars.rotation.x = 0.25;

    // Uncomment for testing second camera position
    // camera.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
    // camera.position.y = -0;
    // camera.position.z = 20;
    // plane.scale.x = 2;
}

function createStars(amount, yDistance) {
    var color = arguments.length > 2 && arguments[2] !== undefined ? arguments[2] : "0x000000";

    var opacity = Math.random();
    var starGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    var starMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({ color: color, opacity: opacity });

    for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
        vertex.z = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 1500;
        vertex.y = yDistance;
        vertex.x = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 1500;

        starGeometry.vertices.push(vertex);
    }


    return new THREE.Points(starGeometry, starMaterial);
}

var timer = 0;

function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    timer += 0.01;
    var vertices = Splane.geometry.vertices;

    for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
        // Ease back to original vertice position while still maintaining sine wave
        vertices[i].x -= Math.sin(timer + vertices[i].randomDelay) / 40 * vertices[i].dx;
        vertices[i].y += Math.sin(timer + vertices[i].randomDelay) / 40 * vertices[i].dy;
        // ((vertices[i].x - vertices[i].originalPosition.x) * 0.1) +
    }



    // Determine where ray is being projected from camera view
    Sraycaster.setFromCamera(SnormalizedMouse, Scamera);

    // Send objects being intersected into a variable
    var intersects = Sraycaster.intersectObjects([Splane]);

    if (intersects.length > 0) {

        var faceBaseColor = intersects[0].face.baseColor;

        Splane.geometry.faces.forEach(function (face) {
            face.color.r *= 255;
            face.color.g *= 255;
            face.color.b *= 255;

            face.color.r += (faceBaseColor.r - face.color.r) * 0.01;
            face.color.g += (faceBaseColor.g - face.color.g) * 0.01;
            face.color.b += (faceBaseColor.b - face.color.b) * 0.01;

            var rInt = Math.floor(face.color.r);
            var gInt = Math.floor(face.color.g);
            var bInt = Math.floor(face.color.b);

            var newBasecol = "rgb(" + rInt + "," + gInt + "," + bInt + ")";
            face.color.setStyle(newBasecol);
        });
        Splane.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;

        intersects[0].face.color.setStyle("#006ea0");
        Splane.geometry.colorsNeedUpdate = true;
    }

    Splane.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
    Splane.geometry.elementsNeedUpdate = true;

    farthestStars.rotation.y -= 0.00001;
    farStars.rotation.y -= 0.00005;
    nearStars.rotation.y -= 0.00011;

    Srenderer.render(scene, Scamera);
}

init();

window.addEventListener("resize", function () {

    Scamera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    Scamera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    Srenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
});

window.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {

    // Normalize mouse coordinates
    SnormalizedMouse.x = event.clientX / window.innerWidth * 2 - 1;
    SnormalizedMouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
});

var introContainer = $('.intro-container');
var skyContainer = $('.sky-container');
var xMark = $('.x-mark');

$('.shift-camera-button').click(function () {
    var introTimeline = new TimelineMax();

    introTimeline.add([TweenLite.fromTo(introContainer, 0.5, { opacity: 1 }, { opacity: 0, ease: Power3.easeIn }), TweenLite.to(Scamera.rotation, 3, { x: Math.PI / 2, ease: Power3.easeInOut }), TweenLite.to(Scamera.position, 2.5, { z: 20, ease: Power3.easeInOut }), TweenLite.to(Scamera.position, 3, { y: 120, ease: Power3.easeInOut }), TweenLite.to(Splane.scale, 3, { x: 2, ease: Power3.easeInOut })]);

    introTimeline.add([TweenLite.to(xMark, 2, { opacity: 1, ease: Power3.easeInOut }), TweenLite.to(skyContainer, 2, { opacity: 1, ease: Power3.easeInOut })]);
});

$('.x-mark').click(function () {
    var outroTimeline = new TimelineMax();

    outroTimeline.add([TweenLite.to(xMark, 0.5, { opacity: 0, ease: Power3.easeInOut }), TweenLite.to(skyContainer, 0.5, { opacity: 0, ease: Power3.easeInOut }), TweenLite.to(Scamera.rotation, 3, { x: 0, ease: Power3.easeInOut }), TweenLite.to(Scamera.position, 3, { z: 50, ease: Power3.easeInOut }), TweenLite.to(Scamera.position, 2.5, { y: 0, ease: Power3.easeInOut }), TweenLite.to(Splane.scale, 3, { x: 1, ease: Power3.easeInOut })]);

    outroTimeline.add([TweenLite.to(introContainer, 0.5, { opacity: 1, ease: Power3.easeIn })]);
});

render();
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brq5Lzvy/2/)

И тут появляется ошибка `Cannot read property 'add' of undefined`

Также на странице есть еще один рендер, но он слишком длинный и не помещается. С ним все хорошо, а с этим плохо. Чтобы не было конфликта имен, я поменял в этом скрипте названия переменных, т.е. вариант, что там могут совпадать переменные отпадает. Очевидно, `.add` получает в функцию `undefined` и поэтому ругается, но почему он получает `undefined` - непонятно. Где здесь ошибка?

Comment: Я наверное кэп, может поставите breakpoint и посмотрите почему у вас undefined...То что Выше недостаточно чтобы воспроизвести ошибку

Comment: @Александр ну если просто посмотреть, что лежит в переменной до того, как положить ее в функцию (console.log(topLight);) он показывает объект THREE.DirectionalLight т.е. все хорошо

Comment: topLight = THREE.DirectionalLight {uuid: "A061A2AC-055C-43AF-82F1-72D50D357549", name: "", type: "DirectionalLight", parent: undefined, children: Array(0), …} Это если прям дебаггером трогать

Comment: Так вы же сами написали void 0

Comment: После того, как делаете какие-то операции с вершинами в геометрии, то после этого нужно вызывать метод(ы) `.computeFaceNormals()` (и `.computeVertexNormals()`) у геометрии для перерасчета нормалей граней (и нормалей вершин), чтобы получить правильные тени при использовании материалов, отличных от `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибки так как у Вас `Sscene = void 0`, это значит `Sscene==undefined`,
надо указать  `Sscene = new THREE.Scene()`.Если смотреть дальше,появляется ошибка

> Uncaught TypeError: THREE.PointsMaterial is not a constructor

,полез смотреть объект,исправил на `new THREE.PointCloudMaterial`.Далее получил ошибку на

> Uncaught TypeError: THREE.Points is not a constructor

исправил на `new THREE.PointCloud`.Далее выходит ошибка

> Uncaught ReferenceError: scene is not defined

,а это как раз `Sscene`.
И все должно render!

Comment: Да, все действительно render) Правда вместо плавающих полигонов получился ровный градиент(

Comment: @Егор Жолнин, тогда отметьте вопрос галочкой.По поводу отрисовки не смотрел,вопрос был не про это)

Comment: @ЕгорЖолнин `THREE.PointCloud()` и `THREE.PointCloudMaterial()` не используются уже несколько лет. В последних ревизиях они `THREE.Points()` и `THREE.PointsMaterial()` соответственно. Лучше (и правильней) всего использовать последнюю ревизию.

Comment: @prisoner849 Так если.`THREE.Points()` и `THREE.PointsMaterial()` тут не работают

Comment: @ЕгорЖолнин Потому что используется r70. Последняя ревизия идет под номером 89.